# How to build the sick_tim package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I build the sick_tim package (http://github.com/uos/sick_tim/tree/groovy)

I cloned the repository into the ~/catkin_ws/src/ folder.

cd ~/catkin_ws/delvel

source setup.*sh

cd ~/catkin_ws

catkin_make

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203752/how-to-build-the-sick_tim-package/) by [naka](https://answers.ros.org/users/21711/naka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2015-02-25**:
ive (so far) never seen/done `source setup.*sh`. Can you try to take out the asterisk? Also, i would recommend adding `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.sh` into your .bashrc so you dont have to source your terminal enviornment for every new terminal you open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your answer.

I cloud build the sick_tim package.

1.Change the name of the folder sick_tim-groovy to sick_tim.

2.rosdep install sick_tim

3.rosmake

---

Originally posted by [naka](https://answers.ros.org/users/21711/naka/) with karma: 18 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0